# How to sort a nested list that contains dictionaries by multiple values and one key of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, key-value, criteria

this is the result of my script for a simple assignment:

So I want to sort the main list by first `points`, second `wins` and if those where equal by alphabetical order of the names of the teams. Also I must reverse the third  conditions', because the main sorted function reverse is set to True

this how far I've gone:

```
all_dicts_lst = [
    {
        "Spain": 0, 
        "wins": 0, 
        "loses": 0, 
        "draws": 3,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "points": 3
    },
    {
        "Iran": 0,
        "wins": 0,
        "loses": 0,
        "draws": 3,
        "goal difference": 0, 
        "points": 3
    },
    {
        "Portugal": 0,
        "wins": 0,
        "loses": 0,
        "draws": 3,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "points": 3,
    },
    {
        "Morraco": 0,
        "wins": 0,
        "loses": 0,
        "draws": 3,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "points": 3,
    },
]

j = sorted(
    [list(x)[0] for x in all_dicts_lst]
)  # this will return the names of countries in a list
print(j)
sorted_all_dics = sorted(
    all_dicts_lst, key=lambda x: (x["points"], x["wins"], j), reverse=True
)
```

But the result is this:

```
Spain  wins:0 , loses:0 , draws:3 , goal difference:0 , points:3
Iran  wins:0 , loses:0 , draws:3 , goal difference:0 , points:3
Portugal  wins:0 , loses:0 , draws:3 , goal difference:0 , points:3
Morraco  wins:0 , loses:0 , draws:3 , goal difference:0 , points:3
```

Comment: Why isn't there a consistent key for the country name, like `'name': 'Spain'`? Using the country name as the key makes it really difficult to process the dictionaries.

Comment: And while dictionaries are now required to preserve insertion order, depending on it to get the name is still a bad idea.

Comment: Yes If I use country name as  a value, sorting will be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `reverse=True`. To sort the numbers in reverse order, negate them when creating the key. The third element of the key should be the name. `j` is the list of all names, not the name of the specific element in the list; since it's the same in every key, it has no effect on the sorting order.

```
sorted_all_dics = sorted( all_dicts_lst, key=lambda x: (-x['points'] , -x['wins'], list(x)[0]))
```

Comment: So x is not the main list it is for each dictionary within the main list? Why?

Comment: When `sorted()` is deciding how to order two elements, it calls `key(element1)` and `key(element2)`. Then it compares those two values.

Comment: If `x` were the main list, how would your `x['points']` work? The list doesn't have `points`, only the dictionaries do.

Comment: *"When sorted() is deciding how to order two elements, it calls key(element1) and key(element2)"* - Not true, it compares the keys computed and stored before the actual sorting begins.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's HOW it does what I said.

Comment: No that's what it does. It doesn't do what you said.

Comment: It calls `key()` on each element, then compares that. @KellyBundy

Comment: @KellyBundy Unless the key function is non-idempotent, I don't see how the distinction you're making matters.

Comment: I think it's done the way it is for speed. Faster to compute the keys only once instead of log(n) times.

Comment: @KellyBundy Right. I was just telling the OP how to think about it, that's just an optimization.

Comment: "Not true, it compares the keys computed and stored before the actual sorting begins".  Could you please explain this by simple example! How does sorted work?

Comment: @aszx6309 All they're saying is that instead of calling the key function every time it needs to compare items, it calls the key function for every item in the array first. Then it uses these saved keys when sorting the list, so it doesn't have to call the key function multiple times for each item.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this :

`j = sorted([list(x)[0] for x in all_dicts_lst], key=lambda x: (all_dicts_lst[x]['points'], all_dicts_lst[x]['wins'], x))`